# Get a service in a IServiceCollection extension

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this extension

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection MyExtension(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

and I need to get information from a service like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        var myService = <<HERE>>();
        options.TokenValidationParameters = this.GetTokenValidationParameters(myService);
    });
```

how can I do that?

I tried to get the `ServiceProvider` after `var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();` and then I send the `serviceProvider`, but this doesn't work..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At the time you are calling `services.AddSomething()`, the service *provider* has not been built from the service collection yet. So you cannot instantiate a service at that time. Fortunately, there is a way to configure services while using dependency injection.

When you do `services.AddSomething(options => …)` what usually happens is that a certain amount of services will be registered with the service collection. And then the passed configuration *action* will also be registered in a special way, so that when the service is later instantiated, it will be able to execute that configuration action in order to apply the configuration.

For that, you need to implement `IConfigureOptions<TOptions>` (or actually `IConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions>` for authentication options) and register it as a singleton. For your purpose, this could look like this:

```
public class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public ConfigureJwtBearerOptions(IMyService myService)
    {
        // ConfigureJwtBearerOptionsis constructed from DI, so we can inject anything here
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        // check that we are currently configuring the options for the correct scheme
        if (name == JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = myService.GetTokenValidationParameters();
        }
    }

    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        // default case: no scheme name was specified
        Configure(string.Empty, options);
    }
}
```

You then register that type in your `Startup`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    // add JwtBearer but no need to pass options here
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, configureOptions: null);

// instead we are registering our configuration type to configure it later
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
```

This is actually the exact same thing that happens when you just do `services.AddJwtBearer(scheme, options => { … })`, just abstracted away, so you don’t need to care about it. But by doing it manually, you now have more power and access to the full dependency injection service provider.

Comment: thanks, it works fine. but I had to change to `.AddJwtBearer();`, because `AddJwtBearer` doesn't have a overload in the extension like `AddJwtBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, string authenticationScheme)`. I don't know if there is a way to do like your example passing `authenticationScheme`.

Comment: @andresdescalzo You’re right, there’s no overload with just the authentication scheme name but no configuration. You can either not pass anything (which will use the default scheme name), or if you need to specify a scheme name, you can pass `null` as the configure action. I’ve adjusted my answer above to fix that.

Comment: In core 2.2 I had to change `IConfigureNamedOptions` into `IConfigureOptions`

Comment: Thanks! Finally a good example for how to actually use the `IConfigureNamedOptions` in conjunction with setting up auth! Love it!

Comment: Using Core 3.1 here... I followed this as closely as I can.  The constructor for `ConfigureJwtBearerOptions` is invoked when the first request is made (and the services are injected to that constructor), but neither `Configure()` method is ever invoked.  What might I be missing?