# How to log unathorized access tries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have .Net Core 2.1 application and I have added JWT Authorization

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                ...
            });
```

How can I log tries to access actions with `[Authorize]` attribute?
I treid to use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963194/7137259 and inject my Logger, but my logger uses Entity DB Context, and I can't inject scoped Logger to `IConfigureNamedOptions`.
Also how can I return normal response when Unauthorized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve your scoped service in JwtBearerEvents, you can modify the response there as well:

```
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
{
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
        {
            var svc = c.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
            c.NoResult();
            c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString()).Wait();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Now I have `System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.` and server is not returning anything

Comment: @Koli96 do you have any other middleware?

Comment: Only standard auto-generated

Comment: @Koli96 does it throw an exception in OnAuthenticationFailed event?

Comment: I can't see it in stack trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177416/discussion-between-koli96-and-alex-riabov).