# Creating a custom RequestCultureProvider - why isn't the Options property initialised?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, threadpool, cultureinfo

I am implementing an *ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApp using Razor Pages* that needs to support multiple cultures. It will run on Azure. It also needs to support *Async methods*.

I am creating a custom `RequestCultureProvider` so I can get the culture from the user's claimsPrincipal if logged-in, as proposed by [Matteo](https://ml-software.ch/posts/writing-a-custom-request-culture-provider-in-asp-net-core-2-1). If the user isn't looged-in, I want to get the culture from one of the default `RequestCultureProviders`:

1. Query string in the URL
2. Cookie `.AspNetCore.Culture`
3. Accept-Language browser setting

After getting the user's culture from whatever source I want to save it in the **".AspNetCore.Culture" cookie**. In this way the user's culture can be obtained in my Razor Pages using

```
var culture = page.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Culture"];
```

- *Note: Setting a response cookie value results in the same value being made available in the request cookie as documented by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.cookies)*

This seems a better approach than attempting to get culture from the current thread because there seems to be a host of problems when doing this with async methods as described in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2986) and [SO - Keep CurrentCulture in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662668/keep-currentculture-in-async-await).

Essentially these problems seem to arise from the fact that the initial thread used by the Default RequestCultureProviders to set culture might not be the same thread used to run my async methods and because there is no guarantee that these different threads will have the same culture as the initial thread I cannot be sure of getting the user's culture in my pages by reading:

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
```

Therefore what I decided to do is to write a **custom RequestCultureProvider** that attempts to obtain culture either from the user's claimsPrincipal, or from the **default RequestCultureProviders** and then sets it in the culture cookie, before returning the required ProviderCultureResult. I've implemented this as follows:

```
public class MyRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
   public override async Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
   {
      string culture = "en";

      if (httpContext == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException();

      if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
         culture = httpContext.User.GetCulture() ?? "en";
      else
      {
         var count = Options?.RequestCultureProviders?.Count ?? -1;
         for (var x = 1; x < count; x++)
         {
            var provider = Options.RequestCultureProviders[x]; //don't invoke initial provider as that's our one
            var val = await provider.DetermineProviderCultureResult(httpContext);
            if (val?.Cultures?.Count > 0)
            { 
               culture = val.Cultures[0].ToString() ?? "en";
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      if (httpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Culture"] != culture)
         httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(".AspNetCore.Culture", culture, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), IsEssential = true });
      return new ProviderCultureResult(culture, culture );
   }
}
```

The custom RequestCultureProvider is added to the middleware in Startup as follows:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en"),
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("de-CH"),
};

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   ...
   app.UseRequestLocalization();

   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   ...
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
   {
      options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: supportedCultures[0].Name, uiCulture: supportedCultures[0].Name);
      options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
      options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
      options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new MyRequestCultureProvider());
   });
   services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

QUESTIONS:

1. Why is Options **null** when I access it in my override DetermineProviderCultureResult() method? It is a Property of the base class as documented by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.localization.requestcultureprovider.options) so how do I initialise it?
2. How else can I get the culture values set by the default RequestCultureProviders? You will note that my DetermineProviderCultureResult() method is async so simply reading the culture value set in the thread doesn't seem like a good idea.
3. How else can I obtain the user's culture for use in my async Page methods?

Any comments on my code are welcome too.

Comment: To help with #3: the `AcceptHeadersRequestCultureProvider` should get the user's preferred culture from the browser's Accept-Language header which could be useful for first requests. The custom provider I use sets the default culture based on a lookup from a request's domain regardless of a user's browser setting on first load, but it inherits from `CookieRequestCultureProvider` and so uses a cookie to make selecting an alternate culture sticky across browsing sessions. There's also `QueryStringRequestCultureProvider` if you want the culture in the querystring for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to create a ctor for `MyRequestCultureProvider` with a RequestLocalizationOptions argument so I can set Options like so:

```
public MyRequestCultureProvider(RequestLocalizationOptions options)
{
   Options = options;
}
```

The code in `Startup.ConfigureServices` then needs changing to pass the Options object when adding it to the collection of RequestCultureProviders like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
   {
      options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: supportedCultures[0].Name, uiCulture: supportedCultures[0].Name);
      options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
      options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
      options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new MyRequestCultureProvider(options));
   });
   services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

I am still interested in hearing comments about this approach to obtaining user culture for a ASP.NET Core WebApp with async Razor page methods

Comment: I initially used your approach in this answer (thank you). However my app is a platform that serves many domains, each with a potentially different set of supported cultures determined by a DB call through another service. Service instances aren't available yet while in `ConfigureServices(..)` so to add one to the constructor of `MyRequestCultureProvider`, I had to make an implementation of `IConfigureOptions<MyOptions>` which takes the service in its ctor, where MyOptions inherits from `RequestLocalizationOptions`. I succeeded based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963194/3626160