# How to add dependency Injection in ISecurityTokenValidator from AddJwtBearer in .net C# Web API

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to call the interface method to additionally validate the **JWT token**, So, I implemented a custom validator by extending the interface `ISecurityTokenValidator` as follows and tried to inject the `IServiceProvider` to call the `AuthService` method `GetUsername`. Here my problem is how to initialize the class with dependency injection in `builder.Services.AddJwtBearer` in startup

Platform & Project: .NET 7 - Web API

**JWT Token Handler**

```
public class MyJwtSecurityTokenHandler : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private int _maxTokenSizeInBytes = TokenValidationParameters.DefaultMaximumTokenSizeInBytes;
    private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyJwtSecurityTokenHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes
    {
        get { return _maxTokenSizeInBytes; }
        set { _maxTokenSizeInBytes = value; }
    }

    bool ISecurityTokenValidator.CanValidateToken => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken)
    {
        return _tokenHandler.CanReadToken(securityToken);
    }

    ClaimsPrincipal ISecurityTokenValidator.ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set up validation parameters or do extra checks
            using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var username = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAuthService>().GetUsername(securityToken);
            }
            return _tokenHandler.ValidateToken(securityToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            validatedToken = null;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
MyJwtSecurityTokenHandler mytokenValidator = new();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("custom validation key")),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = true,
    };
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
    options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(mytokenValidator);
});
```

I tried with lot of tutorials but there is no proper information about how to initialize `mytokenValidator` with dependency injection in `Startup`

Comment: Hopefully this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962770/get-a-service-in-a-iservicecollection-extension

Comment: does IAuthService must be registed as scope instead of singalton?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng - Yes IAuthService is registered as `services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>` - Please let me know how to handle if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I got the answer in **OpenGPT**. Really tremendous and amazing... The proposed solution by **OpenGPT** is working 100% without an error. AI is the new world need to practice how to travel with AI to simplify our work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]